# ReactJS вывести компоненты на страницу

Tags: javascript, reactjs, компоненты

Есть html страница, где будут выводится данные с сервера в определенных блоках.
Допустим блок профиль, где выводится логин пользователя. Каким образом это написать под reactJS? Целиком всю страницу разбить на компоненты или же только один блок.

Например, если это вывод профиля то

```
function user() {
  return (
   <div>
     ... 
   </div>
  );
}
```

и при редеринге я вставлю это в родительский блок.

Comment: как удобнее ... это то же что, на сколько функций разбить код; есть правда момент оптимизации `React.memo`

Answer (score 0):

```
function User (props) {
  return <span>Привет, {props.name}!</span>
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]